# How to check if page load is complete in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, aurelia

I have a script that should run after the entire page load is complete.

Is there a way in Aurelia to figure out if the page load is completed, considering all the sub-modules are loaded ?

The script I am running is a call tracking script that would change targeted numbers on my page. Currently I have it running as the last step inside the config PostRender step and anything that loads after that is not observed by the script. Furthermore this script needs to be run on every page of my website.

Thanks in advance for your inputs.

Answer (score 3):

Have you had a look at the Aurelia lifecycle?

```
export class SomeClass {

  // Navigate To
  constructor() {
      console.log("1. constructor")
  }

  canActivate() {
      console.log("2. canActivate")
  }

  activate() {
      console.log("3. activate")
  }

  attached() {
      // Page has loaded
      console.log("4. attached")
  }

  // Navigate Away
  canDeactivate() {
      console.log("1. canDeactivate")
  }

  deactivate() {
      console.log("2. deactivate")
  }

  detached() {
      console.log("3. detached")
  }
}
```

https://aurelia.io/docs/fundamentals/cheat-sheet

Comment: thanks this is very informative, but does not seems to solve my problem. I was looking for a way to fire a script after load on each page. The above approach would force me to have the script placed on each view inside attached(), which I am l not looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the code of the aurelia afterAttached plugin, the prototype of the attached method is overridden and some custom logic is executed. You could leverage the same method to execute your custom code there, perhaps leverage the aurelia event aggregator to fire a global attached event?

```
import {Controller} from 'aurelia-templating';

export function configure(aurelia) {

  // intercept attached() calls of the View
  var attached = Controller.prototype.attached;
  Controller.prototype.attached = function() {
    attached.call(this);

    // fire your global attached event here, or before the call to attached, depending of what you want to do
  }
}
```

source:
https://github.com/aurelia-ui-toolkits/aurelia-after-attached-plugin/blob/master/src/aurelia-after-attached-plugin.js